# tomboy in12.04 ubuntu add ins tags cant unfold

Tags: unity, 12.04

I have this problem in both gnote and tomboy I cannot access the add ins from preference. I can click addins tab but once in there I see preference, tools, etc but I cannot unfold any of these tags to allow them to work .when I click on triangle they just dont unfold to show addins.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Plus</kbd> to unfold and <kbd>Minus</kbd> to fold.

Comment: brilliant why didnt I think of that?

Comment: now I have another problem, when I try to drag and drop a meesage from evolution it either crashes tomboy (close it) or freeze the computer